# windows randomly freezes on normal mode, runs fine in safe mode

Tags: windows, freeze

old computer that am intending to use as a test server.

- PC had windows XP installed
- PC is rarely used.
- PC started to freeze randomly.
- i started cleaning every bit, and getting every fan to work (considering heating issue).
- after am finished cleaning process; attempted to install windows 7.
- after the first restart during windows setup, on "Completing installation" step. computer froze.
- Second windows 7 installation attempt worked fine, and PC worked fine since then(5 months being occasionally used for an hour or 2).
- 3 days ago, 2nd of January. i purchased 3 additional ram modules to install.
- PC started to freeze randomly again.
- Reinstalled Windows 7. Several attempts failed at Completing Installation step.
- removed the 3 newly installed ram modules.
- Reinstall Windows 7. Several attempts failed at Completing Installation step once again.
- Kept switching between ram modules one at a time, until an attempt succeeded(can fairly say ram modules have nothing to do).
- Now Windows 7 64 bit installed. randomly freezes in normal mode, perfectly fine in `safe mode with networking` or `Diagnostic startup`

random freeze definition: on login screen prior to entering windows login password(idle state). after logging in(in idle state). while checking stuff around, device manager, event viewer, installing software, after 5 seconds of booting to the windows login screen, after 25 mins of heavy cpu load.

while i need help in general; and to comply to rules, i have this specific question:
If i concluded it's either a driver(windows default driver) or a windows service issue, and am currently on `Diagnostic startup` and willing to start enabling a service after service, and driver after driver.

There are plenty of services and some depend on other. **Can someone suggest order that i can follow?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al hamdulellah.

- Disabling `Power` service, stabilized the windows. However it
  disables `Audio` service.
- the absolute reason of my issue was [Processor power management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOu9O.png)* being less than 100%.

Now windows is running on `Normal startup`. All drivers and services are running; i just modified `Balanced`, and `Power saver` plans `Processor power management` value to 100%. `High performance` plan has it set by default.

Now the remaining issue, is what to do during windows installation at `Completing installation` phase!

On a side note though, this is not an answer for my specific question :D
and this post requires proper tags. but i'll sleep for couple days first.

*screenshot taken from laptop. not the desktop in question.